# Slide Show images/Video like Whatsapp status in Android?

Tags: android, slideshow, whatsapp

I want to implement slide show like whatsapp status/Airbnb Image/Videos.

1. Auto Progressing with Timer
2. By Tapping indicators, switch to particular image
3. While scrolling images, timer/slideshow should pause

[image]

Is there any specific library made available ?

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid thanks very much. Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I dont know why guys are downvote this question...Instead of comment on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the link  @burhanuddin-rashid

Show horizontal progress like instagram stories. 
**compile 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:2.0.0'**

https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView